# ReportViewer não funciona no azure

Tags: microsoft-azure, reportviewer

Tenho uma conta gratuita no azure e o relatório não funciona após subir o projeto para o servidor azure (em minha maquina funciona), o erro diz que falta a dll:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

A dll existe na pasta **bin** e em **Copy Local** está = **true** o

Estou usando o Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Comment: Qual é a versão da ReportViewer vc tem como referencia no projeto? Pois ele reclamou que não achou o pacote na versão 11. Talvez vc esteja referenciando uma versão mais atual que ele espera, ou mesmo mais antiga.

Comment: Sim, era a versão que estava desatualizada.

Comment: a solução foi enviar a dll via CopyLocal do Publish na versão correta? A aplicação estava procurando a versão 11 mas você estava enviando outra?

Comment: Boa tarde, Tente incluir as dlls do report viewer na pasta bin do projeto (Ex.: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common). Obs.: O mesmo pode ser feito via FTP